# System.Reactive.Linq with .net core and linux - Could not load type System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime

Tags: .net, linux, system.reactive

I have a console app in .net core and I try to use reactive extensions - I created observable collection using the Observable.FromEventPattern method:

```
 IObservable<EventPattern<BasicDeliverEventArgs>> messages = Observable.FromEventPattern<BasicDeliverEventArgs>(consumer, "Received");
```

When I run the app on windows everything works as expected. When I run it on linux I get this error:`System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.EventRegistrationToken' from assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
   at System.Reactive.ReflectionUtils.GetEventMethods[TSender,TEventArgs](Type targetType, Object target, String eventName, MethodInfo& addMethod, MethodInfo& removeMethod, Type& delegateType, Boolean& isWinRT)
   at System.Reactive.Linq.QueryLanguage.FromEventPattern_[TSender,TEventArgs,TResult](Type targetType, Object target, String eventName, Func`3 getResult, IScheduler scheduler)
`

Is it possible to use reactive extensions with .net core on linux?
I'm using the latest version (3.1.1) of System.Reactive.Linq.

Comment: Possible, Linux is not a reason. Try another overload `public static IObservable<EventPattern<TEventArgs>> FromEventPattern<TDelegate, TEventArgs>(Action<TDelegate> addHandler, Action<TDelegate> removeHandler);` like here https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/pull/947/commits/0e6f48e8a0ee258b7fc1fd8c753f4888283b811a